# Customizing referencing

Tags: cross-referencing

Suppose, I want to add a `\bullet` just before every reference(like [image: this]). How can I do that?

EDIT:
Say, I use a `\ref{key}`, when the `\label{key}` points to a section, it is shown only as a number:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
abc \ref{key}

\section{something \label{key}}
xyz 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, assume I want to put a `\bullet` before the number. What should I do?

I had some random tests with `\renewcommand`, but none of them succeeded.

Comment: Do you mean citation or a reference of an equation? Please provide a complete minimal working example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want this result every time you use `\ref` you can do the following:

```
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}{\textbullet\oldref}
```

MWE (note that the `\label` goes outside the `\section`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}{\textbullet\oldref}

\begin{document}
abc \ref{key}

\section{something}\label{key}
xyz
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you are loading `hyperref`, this package redefines the command `\ref` at the beginning of the document, so if you want to work in this case you have to substitute the above lines with:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\oldref\ref%
  \renewcommand{\ref}{\textbullet\oldref}%
}
```

Comment: Well, that worked for the MWE, but not for my original document.

Comment: @pushpen.paul Then add something in your MWE that can interfere with it.

Comment: `\usepackage{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldref\ref\renewcommand{\ref}{\textbullet\oldref}}`

Comment: Using Marco Daniel's update, it works.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks for the comment, I was outdoor and I'm seen it now.